# Bibliography style "alpha" withour the year

Tags: bibliographies

I am using `\documentclass{amsart}`.

I want to cite the references in  Bibliography with only initials of authors surnames.
For example if the authors are Jaule Calo and Micke Kikdi then then I want to cite them in the text as [CK].

I have tried `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` but none of these do what I want. `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` gives also the year which I do not want.

Comment: There is `alphanum` (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphanum-bst, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphanumb)

Comment: When I do that, I receive the error message "I couldn't open style file alphanum.bst"

Comment: I don't think the file is pre-installed in TeX live or MikTeX due to its (unclear?) license, you have to download it from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/alphanum.bst

Comment: Yes now it works, but for articles with only one author it cites the first three letters of the surname (instead of only the first letter). Example: for the author Jaoule Calo, it cites as `[Cal]` instead of `[C]`

Comment: are you using `amsart` simply because you prefer the style to that of `article`, or do you intend to submit the article to an ams journal?  if the latter, the suggestion to use `biblatex` rather than `bibtex` won't work.  i don't believe the bibitem labels you want would be found objectionable, but they won't work "out of the box", and some investigation and experimentation would be needed.  i assume that you don't refer to multiple items by the same author(s), in which case some "tie-breaker" would be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alphanum` style (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphanum-bst, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphanumb) comes close to what you want. Due to its (unclear?) license it is not available in MikTeX or TeX live, you have to download it from CTAN directly https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/alphanum.bst

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  address   = {London},
}
@book{elkuthor,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Anne Uthor},
  title     = {Towards a Unified Theory on Emela-ntoukas},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  address   = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{elk,elkuthor}
\bibliographystyle{alphanum}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

I suggest you use `biblatex` and Biber: [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864), [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864), [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) as well as [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)

There you can modify the label as you please

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {Towards a Unified Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1977},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  address   = {London},
}
@book{elkuthor,
  author    = {Anne Elk and Anne Uthor},
  title     = {Towards a Unified Theory on Emela-ntoukas},
  year      = {1980},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  address   = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}%

\begin{document}
\cite{elk,elkuthor}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output [E; EU]]

With `\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}%` you get disambiguation numbers, i.e. 'E1' and 'E2' if you have two works by 'Elk'. If you leave the line out, you get letters, i.e. 'Ea', 'Eb'.

Comment: Does your second code works if `documentclass article` is replaced by `documentclass amsart`?

Comment: @gopal Of course it does. But you will have to run Biber and not BibTeX, see the links.

Comment: I just download the bst file for the alphanum, but I don't know where to copy the file in TEXlive directory.

Comment: @XIE For a one-off or for testing it would be enough to just put the `.bst` file into the same directory as your main `.tex` file. If you want to install it in order to use it more often, you should not install it into a directory controlled by your TeX system, you should install it into TEXMFHOME or TEXMFLOCAL (cf https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf, https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-privinst, https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-what-TDS, https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-install-where)

Comment: @moewe Thank you so much. This really solved my problem.